# How do you make an 'attendance table' for a classroom display with an appropriate layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, viewmodel

I have been having a tough time getting an attendance table for a classroom to be displayed in an appropriate fashion.  I have an Attendance table in my database that I can get to display quite easily with the data from just one classroom, but it displays in a way that looks like how it would look if you browsed to the attendance table directly in the database.

It is probably easier for me to explain by showing my work:

I have the following classes:

The actual classroom class, or Course:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceDate { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } // allows Students to be enrolled in a Course
    etc. . .
}
```

My Students:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; } // allows Student to be enrolled in a Course
    etc. . .
}
```

The entity that ties the Students to the Courses:

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Attendance data:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int AttendanceID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public int AttendanceDay { get; set; }  // used to set how many days people are supposed to attend this Course (each course has a different length, some are 10 day courses, some are 3, etc.)
    public bool Present { get; set; }  // absent or present (set to absent by default)
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

The flow of my project has Instructors creating a Course for Students to sign up.  When a Student signs up for a Course, all the necessary Attendance data is input into the Attendance database table with default values (absent every day):

```
for (int i = 0; i < course.AttendingDays; i++)
{
    Attendance newAttendance = new Attendance
    {
        CourseID = course.CourseID,
        StudentID = thisStudent.StudentID,
        AttendanceDay = i + 1,
        Present = false
    };
    db.Attendance.Add(newAttendance);
    db.Save();
}
```

So I have a database table with a bunch of attendance data and I cannot get it to display correctly on the screen, sorted similar to this:

Attendance Day       1       |       2       |       3       |       4       |       5       |

Student1              absent      absent      absent      absent      absent

Student2              absent      absent      absent      absent      absent

Student3              absent      absent      absent      absent      absent

Hopefully you can read that. . .  I assume it is a pretty standard layout for an attendance table.

I have tried sorting the data with Group By:

```
var model = from s in db.Attendance
                             where s.CourseID == 4
                             group s.AttendanceDay by s.StudentID into t
                             select new
                             {
                                 StudentID = t.Key,
                                 Days = t.OrderBy(x => x)
                             };
        return View(model);
```

Which returns an IEnumerable of anonymous type (If I understand correctly), but I cannot seem to get this data to do anything.  If I use 'simpler' table generators (and don't try to Group By the AttendanceDay number) I get the attendance table data just fine, but it is sorted just like it is when you view the actual database table for Attendance, not very useful if you want an Instructor to read and edit the information.

I am thinking I need an appropriate ViewModel to adjust the incoming attendance data in the IEnumerable of anonymous type format, followed by a view that appropriately displays that ViewModel. . . but I am not sure how I would handle that process.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Update:

I am beginning to think I need to take advantage of a "cross-tab report" / "pivoting" and use something like this: http://linqlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pivot&referringTitle=Home

Any pointers?

### Update 2:

Almost completely solved using the below accepted answer, and here is my current controller:

```
        // Generates list of Attendances specifically for current Course
        var attendanceItems = db.Attendance.Where(s => s.CourseID == id);
        List<Attendance> attendanceItemsList = attendanceItems.ToList();
        // End of generating list of Attendances


        // CURRENT PROBLEM AREA - INCOMPLETE
        var student = attendanceItemsList.Select(a => a.Student).Distinct()/*.OrderBy(a => a)*/;  // This works for adding one student, Cannot use OrderBy in its current state - how can I properly order by name?  (right now it will order by id I believe)
        List<Student> StudentList = student.ToList();;

        //
        // Generates list of AttendingDays specifically for current Course
        Course course = db.Courses.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CourseID == id);
        List<int> attDayList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < course.AttendingDays; i++)
        {
            attDayList.Add(i + 1);
        };
        // End of generating list of AttendingDays

        AttendanceReportViewModel model = new AttendanceReportViewModel
        {
            AttendanceDays = attDayList,
            Students = StudentList,
            Attendances = attendanceItemsList,
        };
        return View(model);
```

Comment: Would this involve cross-tab reports and ASP.NET Dynamic Data Content Map? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488545.aspx )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should look into creating a ViewModel that contains a list of days, a list of students, and a list of attendance entries, then simply iterate over the students and within it over the attendance days and then display the attendance record for each.

So the ViewModel would look something like this:

```
public class AttendanceReportViewModel
{
    public List<int> AttendanceDays { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }

    public string IsPresent(Student student, int attendanceDay)
    {
         return Attendances.Single(a => a.StudentID == student.ID && a.AttendanceDay == attendanceDay).Present ? "present" : "absent";
    }
}
```

Make sure to sort all items the way you would like them to appear, but this is simple OrderBy stuff. Also make sure to only load Attendance for the course in question and add any course data to the viewModel you want to show.

Then in your view iterate like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Attendance Day</th>
            @foreach (var attendanceDay in Model.AttendanceDays)
            {
                <th>@attendanceDay</th>
            }
        </tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@student.Name</td>
                @foreach (var attendanceDay in Model.AttendanceDays)
                {
                    <td>@Model.IsPresent(student, attendanceDay)</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
}
```

Just whacked this together for you, so not even sure if my exact code compiles, but I hope it gives you a good starting point. Obviously some styling to the table, etc. should be applied.

### EDIT 1:

To load data into the view model you can just do this in the controller (ultimately this should technically speaking be in repositories and maybe even a service layer)

```
var viewModel = new AttendanceReportViewModel();

viewModel.AttendanceDays = db.Attendance.Select(a => a.AttendanceDay).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a)
...
```

I should also have noted that of course you could also only have loaded the attendance data only into the view model and then produced the AttendanceDays and Students properties in the ViewModel from this data. I avoided this for now as you would most likely want Student data as well.

### EDIT 2

For students it is just more of the same you want all students enrolled in the class, but since you have initialized attendance data for all days up front you can just do this:

```
var viewModel = new AttendanceReportViewModel();

viewModel.AttendanceDays = db.Attendance.Select(a => a.AttendanceDay).Distinct().OrderBy(a => a);
viewModel.Students = db.Attendance.Select(a => a.Student).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Alternatively you can just load this information from the Enrollment table like so:

```
viewModel.Students = db.Enrollment.Where(e => e.CourseID == courseID).Select(e => e.Student).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
```

Please note that I presume that there is a unique constraint between course and student id on the enrollment table and that courseID is what you produce the attendance report for. Also you have Course in your Enrollment table mapped to Student above, which I would assume is incorrect.

Comment: This definitely seems like the right direction.  I am trying to understand (How do I load a list of ints into "list<int> AttendanceDays", for example) how to load the data into the ViewModel now - will update.  Thank you so far.

Comment: To update - I have most of it working (thank you so much).  I can get the table to display appropriately, except I am still working on loading the appropriate students into the list (to test I manually added students to a static list).  Any tips specifically on loading my list with students?  I am trying something like: var student = db.Students.Where(o => o.Enrollments =="Carson");  // This works for adding one student, not all of them - hence my problem | List<Student> StudentList = student.ToList();

Comment: I'm sure I'll figure out the sorting of the table by Student Name.  Thank you very much for all of your help - I was stumped by this one for some time (got side tracked with less elegant solution attempts- I needed to be grounded).  Now on to making it editable so an Instructor can actually edit the attendance!

Answer (score 0):

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_S_GetDaywise_EmpTotalDuties_AttendanceRegister]
        (
        @Month int=null,
        @Year int=null,
        @SCode bigint=null
        )
        AS
            /**Creating TempAllAttendance**/
            CREATE TABLE #TempAllAttendance
            (RecId bigint IDENTITY(1,1),EmpCode BIGINT,Duties FLOAT,AttDay INT, DESIGNATION NVARCHAR(250))
            /**Creating TempAllAttendance**/
            
            /**Creating SumAttendance**/
            CREATE TABLE #SumAttendance
            (Total FLOAT)
            /**Creating SumAttendance**/
            
            
            DECLARE @TotalDuties FLOAT=null
            
         BEGIN
            
            
            
            SET @TotalDuties=(SELECT SUM(ISNULL(Duties, 0)) AS Total FROM tbl_Attendance WHERE ([Month] = @Month) AND ([Year] = @Year) AND (SCode = @SCode))        
            
            INSERT INTO #SumAttendance
            (Total)VALUES(@TotalDuties)
            
            INSERT INTO #TempAllAttendance(EmpCode,Duties,AttDay,DESIGNATION)
            (
                SELECT EmpCode, SUM(ISNULL(Duty1, 0)) AS Duties, DAY(AttendanceDate) AS AttDay,DESIGNATION
                FROM  tbl_Attendance
                WHERE ([Month] = @Month) AND ([Year] = @Year) AND (SCode = @Code)
                GROUP BY EmpCode, AttendanceDate,DESIGNATION 
                
            )   
            /**This is used to get date wise & Swise Total duty When Records Not Saved In tbl_SiteWiseEmployee_TotalAttendance**/
            /**This is used to get date wise & Sise Total duty When Records Saved In tbl_SiteWiseEmployee_TotalAttendance**/
        
       
            /**This is used to get date wise & Swise Total duty**/
                SELECT * FROM #TempAllAttendance
            /**This is used to get date wise & Sitewise Total duty**/
            /**This is used to get date wise Total  duty**/
            SELECT EmpCode,SUM(ISNULL(Duties, 0)) AS Duties,AttDay,DESIGNATION FROM #TempAllAttendance
            GROUP BY EmpCode, AttDay,EmpCode,DESIGNATION
            /**This is used to get Employee SumAttendance**/
            SELECT SUM(Duties) AS Duties,DAY(AttendanceDate) AS AttDay FROM tbl_Attendance
            WHERE (SiteCode = @SCode) AND ([Month] = @Month) AND ([Year] = @Year)  GROUP BY AttendanceDate
            
            /**This is used to get Employee SumAttendance**/
            SELECT * FROM #SumAttendance
            /**This is used to get date wise & Sitewise Total duty AS P**/
                --SELECT RecId,EmpCode,'P' AS Duties,AttDay FROM #TempAllAttendance
                
            SELECT EmpCode,'P' AS Duties,AttDay FROM #TempAllAttendance
            GROUP BY EmpCode, AttDay
            /**This is used to get date wise & Swise Total duty  AS P**/
            
            DROP TABLE #SumAttendance
            DROP TABLE #TempAllAttendance
        END 
    
    
    
    
        private void STotalEmployeeAttendenceReportAsDuty()
        {
            #region  For Displaying page Header region
            lblMonthId.Value = Request.QueryString["Month"];
            lblMonthName.Value = Request.QueryString["MonthName"];
            lblYear.Value = Request.QueryString["year"];
            lblSCode.Value = Request.QueryString["SCode"];
            lblgvSName.Value = Request.QueryString["SName"];
            lblMonth.InnerText = lblMonthName.Value;
            lblYears.InnerText = lblYear.Value;
            lblSName.InnerText = lblgvSiName.Value + "-" + lblSCode.Value;
            #endregion
    
            #region Get SWise Employee Detail
            siAttndncPL.SiteCode = lblSiteCode.Value;
            sAttndncPL.Month = lblMonthId.Value;
            siAttndncPL.Year = lblYear.Value;
            DataTable EmpDt = siteAttndncBL.GetEmployeeNameWithTotalDutiesBySit(siteAttndncPL);
            #endregion
    
            #region Making TempTable.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "EmpCode";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "EmpName";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Designation";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            /**Some Table**/
            DataTable dtdayDuties = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtEmpDayDuties = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtEmpDutiesAsP = new DataTable();
            DataTable dtSumDuty = new DataTable();
            /**Some Region**/
            #endregion
    
            #region Get No Of Days In Month..
            int DaysCount = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Year"]), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Month"]));
            #endregion
    
            #region This will dispaly date value on grid header
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                dc = new DataColumn();
                dc.ColumnName = "0" + i.ToString();
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            }
            for (int i = 10; i <= DaysCount; i++)
            {
                dc = new DataColumn();
                dc.ColumnName = i.ToString();
                dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            }
            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "Total";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            #endregion
    
            #region   /*Adding Site Name Row in Grid View*/
            for (int j = 0; j < EmpDt.Rows.Count + 1; j++)
            {
                DataRow dtrow = dt.NewRow();
                if (j < EmpDt.Rows.Count)
                {
                    dtrow[0] = EmpDt.Rows[j][0];/**this Row Cells EmpCode**/
                    string EmpCode = EmpDt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    // lblEmpCode = EmpDt.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                    dtrow[1] = EmpDt.Rows[j][1];/**this Row Cells EmpName**/
                    dtrow[2] = EmpDt.Rows[j][2];/**this Row Cells DESsgName**/
                    dtrow[DaysCount + 3] = EmpDt.Rows[j][3];/**this Row Cells Duties **/
    
    
                    #region Get EmployeeWise Total Duties.
                    siteAttndncPL.SiteCode = lblSiteCode.Value;
                    siteAttndncPL.Month = lblMonthId.Value;
                    siteAttndncPL.Year = lblYear.Value;
                    DataSet ds = siteAttndncBL.GetEmployeeDayWiseAttendenceBySCode_WOPHD(siteAttndncPL);
                    dtEmpDutiesAsP = ds.Tables["tbl_GetEmpTotalAttendanceOfDayAsP"];/*getting Site Duties as P*/
                    dtEmpDayDuties = ds.Tables["tbl_GetEmpTotalAttendanceOfDay"];
                    dtdayDuties = ds.Tables["tbl_SumOfAllEmpDayWiseDuties"];
                    dtSumDuty = ds.Tables["tbl_TotalSumOfAllEmpAttendance"];
                    TotalSumDuties = Convert.ToDouble(dtSumDuty.Rows[0]["Total"].ToString());
                    #endregion
                }
                if (j == EmpDt.Rows.Count)
                {
                    #region Count Total Duties.
                    dtrow[2] = "Total Duties";
                    dtrow[DaysCount + 3] = TotalSumDuties;/**Sum Of All Main Attendance**/
                    #endregion
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dtrow);
            }
            #endregion
    
            /**Fill Day Wise Attendance In Gridview**/
            #region Day Wise Attendance fill In Gridview..
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    for (int j = 3; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtrows in dtEmpDayDuties.Rows)
                        {
                            /*Matching Emp Code*/
                            if (dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() == dtrows[0].ToString())
                            {
                                /*Matching Emp Category */
                                if (dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() == dtrows[3].ToString())
                                {
                                    TextBox txtDuty = new TextBox();
                                    txtDuty.Text = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString();
                                    txtDuty.Text = dtrows[2].ToString();
                                    /*Matching Date*/
                                    if (Convert.ToString(j - 2) == dtrows[2].ToString())
                                    {
                                        dt.Rows[i][j] = dtrows[1].ToString(); /*Filling  Days wise duty*/
                                    }
                                }
                                /*Matching Emp Category */
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (i == dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                {
                    for (int j = 3; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtrows in dtdayDuties.Rows)
                        {
                            TextBox txtDuty = new TextBox();
                            txtDuty.Text = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName.ToString();
                            txtDuty.Text = dtrows[1].ToString();
                            if (Convert.ToString(j - 2) == dtrows[1].ToString())
                            {
                                dt.Rows[i][j] = dtrows[0].ToString();
    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
    
            #endregion
            /**Fill Day Wise Attendance In Gridview**/
    
            #region Binding Grid
            grdSWiseEmpAttendance.DataSource = dt;
            grdSWiseEmpAttendance.DataBind();
            #endregion Binding Grid
            ViewState["tbldata"] = dt;/*used For Saving Employee Monthly Attendance*/
            Session["reportdata"] = dt;/*used For Printing Employee Monthly Attendance*/
            lblNoOfEmp.InnerText = (grdSWiseEmpAttendance.Rows.Count - 1).ToString();
    
    
        }
    
        void Page_Init(object obj, EventArgs e)
        {
            int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Year"]), Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Month"]));
            int dtinc = 0;
            for (int rowcnt = 0; rowcnt < days + 4; rowcnt++)
            {
                if (rowcnt == 0)
                {
                    BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
                    nameColumn.DataField = "EmpCode";
                    nameColumn.HeaderText = "EmpCode";
                    grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
    
                }
    
                else if (rowcnt == 1)
                {
                    BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
                    nameColumn.DataField = "EmpName";
                    nameColumn.HeaderText = "EmpName";
                    grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
    
                }
                else if (rowcnt == 2)
                {
                    BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
                    nameColumn.DataField = "DESIGNATION";
                    nameColumn.HeaderText = "DESIGNATION";
                    grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
    
                }
                else if (rowcnt == days + 3)
                {
                    BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
                    nameColumn.DataField = "Total";
                    nameColumn.HeaderText = "Total";
                    grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
                    nameColumn.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                }
                else
                {
                    dtinc = dtinc + 1;
                    string formet = "00";
                    TemplateField bfield = new TemplateField();
                    /**Initalize the DataField value**/
                    bfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate2(ListItemType.Header, Convert.ToString(dtinc.ToString(formet)));
                    /**Initialize the HeaderText field value**/
                    bfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate2(ListItemType.Item, Convert.ToString(dtinc.ToString(formet)));
                    /**Add the newly created bound field to the GridView**/
                    grdSEmpAttendance.Columns.Add(bfield);
                }
            }
        }
        
    
    
    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                            <div class="table-responsive">
                                                                <asp:GridView ID="grdSiEmpAttendance" CssClass="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped" Font-Size="Smaller" EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#cc0000" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="10" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Arial" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                                                    BackColor="#f0f5f5" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#990000">
    
                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                    </Columns>
                                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" VerticalAlign="Top"
                                                                        Font-Bold="true" />
                                                                    <RowStyle Font-Size="Small" Height="1" ForeColor="#000000" Font-Italic="true" />
                                                                </asp:GridView>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
    
                                                    </div>








using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

public class GridViewTemplate2 : ITemplate
{
    /**A variable to hold the type of ListItemType**/
         ListItemType _templateType;

    /**A variable to hold the column name**/
         string _columnName;

    /**Constructor where we define the template type and column Name**/
         public GridViewTemplate2(ListItemType type, string colname)
    {

        _templateType = type; /*Stores the template type*/
         _columnName = colname;/*Stores the column name*/
    }

    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (_templateType)
        {
            #region For Use TemplateFields.

            case ListItemType.Header:
                /*Create a New Label control and add it to the container*/
                Label lbl = new Label();/*Allocates the new label object*/
                
                lbl.Text = _columnName;/*Assigns the name of the column in the lable*/
                lbl.Font.Name = "Calibri";
               
                //lbl.CssClass = "form-label";
                //lbl.Font.Bold = true;
                container.Controls.Add(lbl);/*Adds the New created label control to the container*/
               
                break;

            case ListItemType.Item:
                /**Creates a New Text box Control And Add It to the container**/
                TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();/*Allocates the new text box object*/
                tb1.DataBinding += new EventHandler(tb1_DataBinding);/*Attaches the data binding event*/
                tb1.CssClass = "vertical-text";
                string bxid = "txt" + _columnName;
                tb1.ID = bxid.Trim().ToString();
                tb1.Width = new Unit(35, UnitType.Pixel);
                tb1.Height = new Unit(15, UnitType.Pixel);
                //tb1.Style.Add("font-size", "8pt;");
                tb1.Font.Name = "Calibri";
               
                tb1.Columns = 3; /**Creates a column with size 4**/
                container.Controls.Add(tb1);/**Adds the New created textbox to the container**/
                break;

            case ListItemType.EditItem:
              

                break;

            case ListItemType.Footer:
                CheckBox chkColumn = new CheckBox();
                chkColumn.ID = "Chk" + _columnName;
                container.Controls.Add(chkColumn);
                break;

            #endregion
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the event, which will be raised when the binding happens.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    /// 
    void tb1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region For Use DataBinding Fields..
        TextBox txtdata = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)txtdata.NamingContainer;
        object dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _columnName);
        if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
        {
            if (dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "0".ToString() || dataValue.ToString().Trim()=="")
            {

                txtdata.Text = "";
                //txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlanchedAlmond;
                //txtdata.ReadOnly = true;
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 8;
            }

            if (dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "777" || dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "L")
            {

                txtdata.Text = "L";
                txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SandyBrown;
                //txtdata.ReadOnly = true;
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
            }
            

            if (dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "888" || dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "WO")
            {

                txtdata.Text = "WO";
                txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                //txtdata.ReadOnly = true;
                txtdata.Width = 36;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
            }
   

            if (dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "999" || dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "PH")
            {

                txtdata.Text = "PH";
                txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
                //txtdata.ReadOnly = true;
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
            }
   
            if (dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "1111" || dataValue.ToString().Trim() == "CL")
            {

                txtdata.Text = "CL";
                txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Bisque;
                //txtdata.ReadOnly = true;
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
            }
   
      

           
            if ((dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "1111") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "CL") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "2997") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "HD") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "777") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "L") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "888") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "W/O")  (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "1")&& 
            {

                txtdata.ReadOnly = false;
                txtdata.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
                txtdata.Text = dataValue.ToString();
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
                txtdata.Font.Bold = true;
            }
            if ((dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "1111") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "CL") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "2997") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "HD") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "777") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "L") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "888") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "WO") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "1776") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "3000") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "T") && (dataValue.ToString().Trim() != "1000") && 
            {

                txtdata.ReadOnly = false;
                txtdata.Text = dataValue.ToString();
                txtdata.Width = 35;
                txtdata.Height = 25;
                txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
                txtdata.Font.Size = 7;
                txtdata.Font.Bold = true;
            }
           
            //else
            //{
            //    txtdata.ReadOnly = false;
            //    txtdata.Text = dataValue.ToString();
            //    txtdata.Width = 35;
            //    txtdata.Height = 25;
            //    txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
            //    txtdata.Font.Size = 8;
            //    txtdata.Font.Bold = true;
            //}


        }
        else
        {
            txtdata.Text ="";
            txtdata.Width = 35;
            txtdata.Height = 25;
            txtdata.CssClass = "form-control input-sm m-bot15";
            txtdata.Font.Size = 8;
            txtdata.Font.Bold = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }

}
```