# How to Generate a calendar showing booking of Environments in a Date range in MVC

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to show the booking of Environments(booked by Environment Booking system) in any tabular form,  where column head consist of dates like timetable dates and left column consist of environment names  and environment booked shown in some custom color.

please suggest the approach how to create that dynamic table, is there any free full jquery option available?
I have seen Daypilot, Kendo and Dhtmlx etc but they are any how paid ... so can't use them. 
please help.

Edit 1

My class

```
public class Booking()
{
public int bookingID{get;set;}
public string Envname {get;set;}
public string bookedby{get;set;}
public string projectname {get;set;}
public Datetime stDate {get;set;}
public Datetime edDate {get;set;}
}
```

In my controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

    List<Booking> booking = new List<Booking>()
    {
    new Booking{
    bookingID=1;
    Envname ="ENV1";
    bookedby="SIA";
    edDate = Convert.ToDateTime(26/6/2016);
    stDate = Convert.ToDateTime(6/5/2016);
    projectname ="LK"
    },
new Booking{
    bookingID=2;
    Envname ="ENV1";
    bookedby="KK";
    edDate = Convert.ToDateTime(9/9/2016);
    stDate = Convert.ToDateTime(21/10/2016);
    projectname ="IND"
    },
new Booking{
    bookingID=3;
    Envname ="ENV2";
    bookedby="PL2";
    edDate = Convert.ToDateTime(11/11/2016);
    stDate = Convert.ToDateTime(12/6/2016);
    projectname ="WLLAA"
    },
new Booking{
    bookingID=4;
    Envname ="ENV1";
    bookedby="SIA";
    edDate = Convert.ToDateTime(6/5/2016);
    stDate = Convert.ToDateTime(24/6/2016);
    projectname ="TODB"
    },
    }
    return View(booking );
    }
```

Comment: There are many free javascript grid libraries but honestly they all suck. Do you need to _edit_ this grid or just display it? If just display it you don't even need jquery or javascript

Comment: just want to show. actually  i am stuck how to show multiple  booking of an environment in a row, I mean I have to crate n table (rows) inside main table(row) because there is no limit of multiple booking. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Do you just want a report? (no writeback to the databasde) Is the data in SQL Server? I actually suggest building it in SSRS. Otherwise maybe something like this: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/25167/simple-advanced-pivots-with-c-and-asp-net or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537047/how-do-you-make-an-attendance-table-for-a-classroom-display-with-an-appropriat

Comment: yes some kind of report , it show which environment is booked in a date range week wise . there may be N number of booking for shared environment by the teams so i have to show them too in same row with different color. I am working in your given direction and crated my own table with date in header and now creating table rows with Environment but stuck with multiple booking case. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Do you mean a database table or a HTML table in ASP? Are you comfortable coding in ASP.Net? Are you comfortable writing SQL statements? Can you post the database tables you are reading from? Are you using LINQ?

Comment: I mean HTML table , i just need the logical hint in any MVC or ASP.net how to put date column in head and below how to show booked environment details and availability dates, Iam comfortable in SQL , please check the question with edit.   @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: So one way is to write your razor view correctly so that it dynamically generates the correct number of HTML table rows and columns based on the data returned from the controller. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368266/dynamic-columns-report-by-using-mvc. I've done this kind of thing before but I don't have the time right now to write it out for you. Perhaps you should first write a razor  view which only lists the environments down the side with one column. Then work out how to get the dates as columns. Then work out how to get multiple bookings on each row.

Comment: Failing that... this is a JS one that seems to be free. https://github.com/timekit-io/booking-js though I don't know if it supports multiples

Comment: thanks for direction .@Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have created the table successfully without using JavaScript or Jquery using loop in my razor view by passing the list to view and loop thorough each item .thanks for hints in the comments @Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if this can help:

http://wpandsuch.com/add-a-calendar-date-picker-to-a-form-with-jquery/